# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't find host php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

I've made a php project and it worked perfectly untill yesterday.
Suddenly I am getting this error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Host is unknown.

I am using a PDO connection through a database class :

```
abstract class Db{

private static $conn = NULL;

public static function getInstance(){
    if (!isset(self::$conn)) {
        self::$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=imdterest","root","");
    }
    return self::$conn;
  }
}
```

I know this question has been asked before but I could not find a solution that worked for me.
I have already tried to change host to 127.0.0.1 and that didn't work either, I also tried to remove the port and that didn't help also.

I have only hosted this on a localhost with xampp.

Any advice would be helpfull. Thank you.

Comment: "Suddenly" ? No updates, network changes, etc?

Comment: are u sure mysql is running?

Comment: can you check if mysql is running?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile mysql is running fine , I can acces my localhost just fine

Comment: The Port is also correct?

Comment: @BartFriederichs I changed it yesterday to host my database online , and then changed it back to normal. It didn't work then either.

Comment: @TobiasF. the port in my Xampp seems to be correct , but it worked before without the port part

Comment: 1. What is the error message when you are using an IP address. 2. what is the file and line number where the error occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found my error and it was very very silly.
I basically had the exact same project stored in a github folder and Xampp folder.
I kept changing the github folder project in the hopes that the Xampp one got altered -_- .

So yeah I was an idiot XD

It now works like a charm.